# su between regular user accounts fails with "su: incorrect password"

Tags: linux, sudo, su

user1 wants to su to user2 (both are non-root).  When user1 runs `su - user2`, he's prompted for user2's password as expected, but the password is never accepted.

```
user1@host $  su - user2   (switch from user1 to user2)
Password:
su: incorrect password
user1@host $
```

user2 is a valid, unlocked account with a real shell specified in `/etc/passwd`.  You can SSH as user2 to the box (`ssh user2@host`).  Also, in my testing user1 and user2 have the same password, so it's not a matter of a password mismatch (supplying user2's password when user1's is expected, or vice versa).

Oddly, `pam_tally2` increments user2's failed login but nothing is logged to `/var/log/secure`.  For that matter, **nothing** is logged to anything else in `/var/log`, either.

I can work around this by adding this line to sudoers:
`user1 ALL=(ALL) /bin/su`

... and running the command with sudo:
`user1@host $  sudo su - user2`

However, I'd like to find out why I can't just run su.

This is a RHEL5 box that has STIGs applied automatically with Aqueduct, so I'm not sure what would have been changed in `/etc/pam.d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having your `/etc/pam.d/su` I can only guess that:

- probably `su` is restricted to the `wheel` group using `auth required pam_wheel.so`
- the pam stack is misconfigured

For a hint on how to use `pam_tally2` in RHEL5, check [here](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/os/redhat/rhel5-guide-i731.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.3.2),

Comment: You fixed it!  Yes, the `auth required pam_wheel.so` line was uncommented.  Thank you, I'm new at this.